# no changes impacting asset ownership found

Tags: anchor, rust, transaction

When I try to approve a transaction on phantom wallet, it shows `No changes impacting asset ownership found` in Estimated Changes section.

[image]

Any solutions or ideas?

Comment: Is it an issue or is it something happens in general?

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled on this error message and likely found the solution:

**Your "To" and "From" address is (most likely) the same.**

Phantom is trying to warn you that you are trying to pay yourself money, which is a net-zero change to your account, minus a network fee.

Make sure your Phantom wallet has the right account selected. You'll want to be logged into your 'sender' wallet.

Answer (score 1):

you can have this message if you are approving an empty transaction too (a transaction without instructions inside)

Answer (score 1):

No assets being transferred or otherwise impacted by this transaction.

Most likely trying to send something to yourself.